# accuracy calculation

Tags: matlab

I have implemented a texture recognition algorithm in MATLAB and it works well. Now, my next step is to summarize with the accuracy percentage. Now, I would like to summarize my work and attribute an accuracy to my algorithm.

I have around 1000 images and only one training image. The feature vectors are available for all the images in the dataset. Right now I am getting the top 5 matches from the dataset for a given image. Everything works well!

now i want to calculate accuracy for all the images in the dataset and average it out to get the final accuracy. Can someone tell me what could be the best method for calculating the accuracy and precision and how should i proceed in case of large datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common practice in your case is to give the mean rank of the correct answer (the ground truth), eventually after querying for only the 5 best matches. An alternative is to give the percentage of tests where the good solution was in the top 5.

Search for related papers in your field, this will give you some hints on what to choose.